# How to open SMS intent to read (not send) message?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` to listen to incoming SMS. I was successful catch SMS body and SMS number from the sender. I want to open the SMS application with the body and the number using Android Intent(similar when you receive an SMS and open SMS app to see detail). How can I do it in Android 5.0? I am using the bellow code, but it is for sending a message. It means it opened the window that has number and body +send button. I don't want that window. I just want reading GUI

```
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", SMSNumber);
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",SMSBody);
        smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do it in Android 5.0?

[`ACTION_VIEW` does not take extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW). It does take a `Uri`. If you have read access to the `Sms` provider, you are welcome to try to find the message in the inbox, then try `ACTION_VIEW` with the `Uri` to that message. However, there is no requirement that any Android device have an app with an activity that supports this.

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand your solution. I just want to open the detail of incoming SMS using default SMS app in Android phone (same as when you receive a SMS, and you open it by your hand, but I try to implement it by using programming in this case)

Comment: @user8430: What you want to do is not directly possible. The only way to show the content of the text message reliably is if you show it yourself, by writing your own UI.

Comment: I just do it in simple way. In that case, I assume that the phone has default SMS app. So, I just call the default SMS app by Intent. I tried it in 5.1.1 and it work but it does not work in 5.0 version. It displayed sending GUI, instead of reading GUI

Comment: @user8430: There are ~2 billion Android devices. These are spread across thousands of different device models. These models will have hundreds of different "default SMS apps", because device manufacturers typically ship their own. Plus, users are welcome to install their own SMS client apps. No SMS client app has to support what you are trying to do. So, while it is nice that at least one Android 5.1.1 device happens to have an SMS client that happens to support this, do not assume that it will work on any other device.