# Android open specific SMS-Thread by its Thread-ID

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sms

my plan is to open an SMS-Conversation Thread by its thread-id. My Code is:

```
    long threadId = Long.parseLong(THREAD_ID);


    Intent defineIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    defineIntent.setData(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/"+threadId));
    context.startActivity(defineIntent);
```

But i get the following error:

> 09-27 16:01:07.696: ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to
>   handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=content://mms-sms/conversations/3 }

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

J Doe ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678042/how-to-open-sms-intent-to-read-not-send-message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution by myself. It works because every msg from one specific Number comes to one thread. If you use a "new-sms-intent" with the Number you've got the SMS from (not the Contact-Name) it will open the whole conversation.

Just one line:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", "SMS_NUMBER_AS_STRING_HERE", null)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is improvement of [answer of J. Doe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39752632/1891118).

Using `"SMS_NUMBER_AS_STRING_HERE"` is not a full solution. You have to get value of column `Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS` and use it instead just a number.

Another correction is setting default SMS package for the intent. This is needed for two reasons:

1. Avoid system 'Choose app' dialog.
2. Only default SMS app can send messages, so if user choose another app, it probably will get an error message (like I got with Hangout) despite the fact that you use `ACTION_VIEW` intent.

Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", address, null));
intent.setPackage(Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context));
```